Isomorphic Subfields of a Galois Extension
I'm brushing up on some Galois theory, and would like a sanity check on my argument to the following exercise, please.

Let $\mathbb{Q} \subseteq K$ be a Galois extension with a Galois group isomorphic to $S_5$, and let $L = K^C$ the fixed field of the cyclic subgroup $C \subseteq S_5$ generated by $\tau = (12345)$. Find the number of different subfields $L'$ in $K$ which are isomorphic to $L$ (including the case $L'=L$.

My argument is structured as follows:

Conjugate subgroups of $\text{Aut}_{\mathbb{Q}}(K)$ corresponds to isomorphic subfields of $K$, so it suffices to determine subgroups conjugate to $C$ in $S_5$.
Sylow theory tells us there are 6 subgroups conjugate to $C$, so I believe there should be 6 subfields isomorphic to $L$.

Thanks in advance.

You could note that  $C=C_5$ is the cyclic group of order $5$, and ${\rm Gal}(K,\Bbb Q)\cong S_5$ is the Galois group. There are six subgroups in $S_5$ isomorphic to $C_5$, and hence six subfields isomorphic to $L$. For a proof see for example here.
